# Javascript Filter Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am practicing how to use filter and wanted to create a simple "portfolio" mockup that lets you click a button and it filters the results. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working.

```js
let posts = [...document.querySelectorAll('.post')];
     let btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')];
        
    
    for( let b of btns) {
        b.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let buttonClass = b.getAttribute('id');
            posts.filter((post) => {
                return post.classList.contains(buttonClass);
            });
        });
    }
```

```css
 .container {
            width: 90%;
            margin: 2rem auto;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-auto-rows: 200px;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }
        
        .post {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        
        .blue {
            background: #192331;
        }
        
        .black {
            background: #171717;
        }
```

```html
<button id="all" class="btn">All</button>
  <button id="blue" class="btn">Blue</button>
  <button id="black" class="btn">Black</button>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="post blue"></div>
    <div class="post black"></div>
    <div class="post black"></div>
    <div class="post blue"></div>
    <div class="post blue"></div>
    <div class="post black"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Your filter is working well. But It only get result of elements that you are filtered. You should add more CSS to show/ hide elements like @william-wang did.

Comment: If I wanted the filter to not switch abruptly though, and rather a smooth transition, would display still work?

Comment: @webdev1995 you can use williams asnwer and add keyframes to the CSS for .hide and  .show, except use opacity. Then in the conditional use a setTimeout function to switch the elements display to none and block respectively. Its a bit of a hack but it will work. Problem is you are using grid, so if you have a number of photos that does not match your grid layout, it could be an issue... I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working off of Williams answer and covering the animation... Do the **transition animation** with **opacity** and **keyframes** in **CSS**, then use a **setTimeout** that sets the **display** to **none** after the opacity animation runs.

So you have a **setTimeout** that runs *10 ms* after the opacity conditional fires, this allows the animation to fire and then sets the **display** to *none*, basically removing the opaque elements from view on the browser. Sense the classes are set up as a toggle in JS, you use them in your **setTimeout** function.

See the code below.

```js
let posts = [...document.querySelectorAll('.post')];
let btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')];
let cont = [...document.querySelectorAll('.container')];

function setDisplay(el) {
  if(el.classList.contains('hide')){
    el.style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    el.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

for (let b of btns) {
  b.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let buttonClass = b.getAttribute('id');
    posts.forEach((post) => {    
      if (post.classList.contains(buttonClass)) {
        post.classList.remove('hide')
        post.classList.add('show')
        setTimeout(setDisplay(post), 10)
      } else {
        post.classList.remove('show')
        post.classList.add('hide')
        setTimeout(setDisplay(post), 10)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.post {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.blue {
  background: #192331;
}

.black {
  background: #171717;
}

.show {
  animation: showme .5s ease-in;
}

@keyframes showme {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: hideme .5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes hideme {
  0% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="post" class="btn">All</button>
<button id="blue" class="btn">Blue</button>
<button id="black" class="btn">Black</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post blue"></div>
  <div class="post black"></div>
  <div class="post black"></div>
  <div class="post blue"></div>
  <div class="post blue"></div>
  <div class="post black"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you so much! So setTimeout lets you transition from display none to display block?

Comment: No setTimeout is exactly what it sounds like, it pauses the code (times out) for the set time in the function in our case, `10 ms`. So basically you are giving Javascript time to run the opacity animation before it runs the function that handles the display turning from none to block and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Filter doesn't work. Just use toggling way to add/remove `show` and `hide` class to the post containers.

```js
let posts = [...document.querySelectorAll('.post')];
     let btns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.btn')];
        
    
    for( let b of btns) {
        b.addEventListener('click', () => {
            let buttonClass = b.getAttribute('id');
            posts.forEach((post) => {
              if (post.classList.contains(buttonClass)) {
                post.classList.remove('hide')
                post.classList.add('show')
              }
              else {
                post.classList.remove('show')
                post.classList.add('hide')
              }
            });
        });
    }
```

```css
.container {
            width: 90%;
            margin: 2rem auto;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
            grid-auto-rows: 200px;
            grid-gap: 1rem;
        }
        
        .post {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        
        .blue {
            background: #192331;
        }
        
        .black {
            background: #171717;
        }
        .show {
          display: block;
        }
        .hide {
          display: none;
        }
```

```html
<button id="post" class="btn">All</button>
  <button id="blue" class="btn">Blue</button>
  <button id="black" class="btn">Black</button>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="post blue"></div>
    <div class="post black"></div>
    <div class="post black"></div>
    <div class="post blue"></div>
    <div class="post blue"></div>
    <div class="post black"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Display isn't affected by transition in css right? How would i get this to have a smooth transition?